# Service account Authentication in google analytics api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics-api

I use google analytics api .net . I use exactly these sample codes [here](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Analytics/Daimto-Google-Analytics-Sample/Daimto-Google-Analytics-Sample).
When i use Oauth 2.0 , i have no problem and every thing works good . But when i want to use Service account Authentication , i get null here ( x is null)

```
 var x = DaimtoAnaltyicsReportingHelper.Get(service, "78110423", "10daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions", options);
```

What is missed ?

(I already created p12 file and have service account email )

Answer (score 1):

The solution :
I needed to add Service account email (which has been made in google developers consol) to user management in google analytics panel and give it permission .